# Visual Studio 2017 debugging

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio version 15.8.7 and .NET framework Version 4.6.01590 and writing in VB.NET. For some reason I am unable to run **any** code.

When trying to run:

```
    Module Module1

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        Console.ReadKey(True)    
    End Sub

End Module
```

It just does not run. The console pops up for a split second and then I get "The program '[17080] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."
When running it with Ctrl+F5 I only get "Press any key to continue..." and no "Hello World!".

When trying to run Windows Form App, nothing pops up and I get the same "has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

I tried reinstalling Visual Studio, but nothing changed.

Any recommendations?

Best Regards,
SilverR

Comment: Try repairing your .NET Framework installation and/or targeting a different version.

Comment: Just remove the True from the Comsole.ReadKey. `Console.ReadKey()`

Comment: Tried repairing the .NET Framework and also targeted .NET Framework 2.0. That did not change anything. I still am not able to run any code.

Mary- the problem is not this exact program. I just used it to make an example. The problem rose when I was trying to modify a bigger program I made a while back.

Comment: Maybe you should look for problem in Visual Studio. I recomend to add a proper tags to the question (Visual Studio, Visual Studio 2017 )

Comment: Yes, it appears that the problem is with Visual Studio. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling .NET Framework but that did not change anything. Our IT department is also out of ideas and recommends a clean Windows install if nothing else helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was caused by Palo Alto Traps anti- malware software, that wouldn't let any *.exe run that was generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: There was an exeption made for the folder where I run all the Visual Studio programs from.